# Unauthorized on valid JWT in nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, passport-jwt

I'm developing an nodejs app, I already handle a register, login and profile api which work perfectly.
I am using passport-jwt to generate a valid JWT to access the user profile.
The first version of my app is monolithic.

I wanted to switch on docker microservices architecture for my app.
I succeeded on separate register, login and profile into 3 separate containers. My register and login microservices are working great.

The only problem is that the JWT that is generated by register or login services seems to be invalid (Unauthorized on profile api) but it wasn't the case when my app was monolithic.

I didn't change my code.

Did anyone experienced that issue ? Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) because when you ran your app as a single monolith all the requests originated/served from the same domain name which is not the case when you split that into different services running in separate containers.

I had faced similar issues while trying to implement [ldapauth-fork](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ldapauth-fork) and solved it by setting explicitly the below http header -

`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://yourprofileservice');`

Check on this and if you still face issues please do share the errors you receive on your end.